# openGL glx.h missing form xcode 4 mac lion

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

I'm trying to setup an example project, which uses  [GLSDK](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/index.html) . I set it up with premake, (setting the projects base sdk to 10.6 since I'm on xcode 4) but when I try to compile I get "GL/gl.h not found" from the example files.

So I manually add the opengl framework and change GL/gl.h to OpenGl/gl.h and it works, but then I get the same error for a different line , and now I realize that header doesn't exist in the opengl framework, even though it should.

I can see it getting reference in other programs and i see it example code all the time. But for some reason it doesn't exist on my computer?

Or am I missing something like I usually do. Just for reference I'm tying to set up the example projects  [here](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Building%20the%20Tutorials.html)  and I'm certain my screwing something up.

Comment: Just FYI: the SDK has not been tested to work on MacOSX.

Comment: I still expect glx.h to exist

Comment: @TauraJGreig: Why? MacOS X natively doesn't use X11. Does Lion even still ship with a X11 server? My Mac is a bit outdated and only has Leopard (not even Snow Leopard) installed.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293
If you install XQuartz you get X11 which has glx.h

Comment: @user149100: Post your comment as an answer so it can be accepted and upvoted.

Answer (score 4):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5293

If you install XQuartz you get X11 which has glx.h