# Trying to port a linux-based open source C++ project that uses X11 into OSX. I've installed XQuartz: now what?

Tags: c++, linux, xcode, macos, opengl

I am trying to port a C++ project to OS X. I am getting a file not found error from the compiler on this line:

```
#include <GL/glx.h>
```

To solve this problem, this question lead me to download xQuartz and run the installer. [openGL glx.h missing form xcode 4 mac lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516637/opengl-glx-h-missing-form-xcode-4-mac-lion)

Now what do I do? When I search the X11 folder I don't see a glx.h file

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516637/opengl-glx-h-missing-form-xcode-4-mac-lion

Comment: Generally on OS X you don't use GLX. You can use X11 if you absolutely must, but it does not even come pre-installed in most OS X distributions, you'll have to fetch your OS X install DVD and install it (XQuartz).

Answer (score 1):

Does the project use a configure script? If so, there's a good chance it uses the `AC_PATH_X` or `AC_PATH_XTRA` macro. And then it will accept `--x-includes=<dir>` and `--x-libraries=<dir>` options.  For Xquartz, try:

```
./configure --x-includes=/opt/X11/include --x-libraries=/opt/X11/lib
```

If it doesn't use a configure script, you'll need to pass those paths to the compiler with `-I` and `-L`, respectively.

Comment: how do i know if the project uses a configure script?

Comment: Do you know how you would build it on a Linux system? If not, then I'd start by figuring that out. If so, does that involve invoking `./configure`?